# Ionic 2 add effects to image

Tags: image-processing, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my application I have a section that user selects an image and can set some effects to it. like adding a hat on his head or something else.
I know that the ionic is not a very good choice for this kind of applications but I have to do this in this way. So I want a help to figure out how do this by my own or if it's a library out there that can help through this.

Comment: you can use adobe creative SDK, this is awesome library.

Comment: I used that but it has two problems. 

1 : looks like it has some problems with ionic 2 since I have problems with building project

2 : it requires an authentication level by adobe that I don't want user deal with that.